# How to style multi chained select buttons.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen, chained-select

Our project consisted of multi select buttons. Since the styling of select and option tags itself is difficult, we used chosen.js to style the select and option tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="$url_link/css/user_css/chosen.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="$url_link/plugins/chosen_v1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
```

Once the styling of the select buttons were possible, we needed to see if the multi chained operation works. It failed.

The reason was about how chosen.js works. Chosen. js first converts the select and option tags into ul and li tags and then styles those tags. But once styled it doesnt convert it back to select and option tags.

Hence multi chained functionality fails after styling. how can we ensure that the style can take place and fuctionality of chaining doesnt get affected ??

Answer (score 0):

To do this, we need to bind these li and ul tags back to option and select tags.

```
\$("#manager").chained("#rmanager");
            \$("#manager").trigger("chosen:updated");
            \$("#rmanager").bind("change", function(){
            \$("#manager").trigger("chosen:updated")
        });
```

In this example, manager is chained to rmanager field. I hope this helps you guys. took me 2 days to figure it out all these dependencies.